# Get active gtk window in python

Tags: python, gtk

How would I get a handle to the active `gtk.Window` in python? (not a window I created, but the currently focused window).

Comment: I suppose it breaks down to two questions.  1) What window is active?  2) Is this window a gtk window?  What OS are you using?  Any answer will be OS specific.

Comment: Hi Steven. Thanks for the comment. I am working with ubuntu linux.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but on Ubuntu you can get the active window ID with `import subprocess; subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'xdotool getactivewindow'])`

Comment: This is a question that needs to be answered on the level of the window manager or compositor, not GTK+; the widget toolkit only works within a single process (or `GtkApplication`, of which there apparently can be >1 per process, though I'm not sure anyone has ever found any use for that).

Answer (score 5):

The answer is actually not OS-specific -- you can do it within GTK. You can get a list of all the toplevel windows from the application using `gtk.window_list_toplevels()`, then iterate through it until you find one where `window.is_active()` returns `True`.

If you want to consider other windows than the ones from your application, then you could try `gtk.gdk.screen_get_default().get_toplevel_windows()` but this will only get you GDK windows and not GTK windows, because you have no way of knowing whether those GDK windows are actually associated with GTK windows.

Comment: This is not what I want - window.is_active() returns whether a given window is active, I need the actual window object. I have a handle to the wnck window or to the gtk.gdk.Window, but I need the gtk.Window object.

Comment: The second paragraph is exactly my problem - I have a list of gdk windows (I can also use wnck and get a similar list of wnck windows) but I need the gtk windows. My real effort is to determine what type of widget inside the window has user focus (e.g. text-edit).

Comment: There's no way of knowing that - perhaps the focused widget is some custom widget that your program doesn't even know about! I don't think what you want is possible.

Comment: `gtk.window_list_toplevels()` returns as `[]` for me. I"m on Ubuntu with plenty of windows open,

Comment: Did you read the answer? That won't give you windows from other applications.

Comment: Based on this it is easy to get the actual window object: `for window in Gtk.Window.list_toplevels(): if window.is_active(): break`

Comment: That doesn't give you windows from other applications.

Answer (score 0):

*[Note: This answers the question as the OP originally phrased it, which other readers will probably be searching for - not the very different question that they changed it to in comments on the other answer.]*

If you have a `GtkApplication` and have added your `GtkWindow`s to it - which you should probably do, because `GtkApplication` can do lots of really cool stuff! - then you can use `GtkApplication`'s much simpler API dedicated to this purpose:

[`Gtk.Application.get_active_window()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Application.html#Gtk.Application.get_active_window):

> Gets the “active” window for the application.
>
> The active window is the one that was most recently focused (within the application). This window may not have the focus at the moment if another application has it — this is just the most recently-focused window within this application.