# How do I get the title of the current active window using gdk and Rust?

Tags: linux, rust, gtk, gtk3, gdk

I'm trying to get the title of the active window using Rust and `gdk` but I can only find `gtk::set_title` without `gtk::get_title`.

Comment: Sure it's there. https://docs.rs/gtk/0.8.1/gtk/trait.GtkWindowExt.html#tymethod.get_title

Comment: That's `gtk::GtkWindow` I want `gdk::Window`, `GtKWindow.get_title()` get will get the title you set for your application, but `gdk::Window.get_title()` should get the title of whatever window is running.

Comment: Are you sure the functionality even exists in `gdk`? I can find [`gdk_window_set_title`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-set-title), but not `gdk_window_get_title`.

Comment: It doesn't exist and and that has sense. Read this https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/gdk_window_get_title-623001/

Comment: Also, this can be useful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166169/get-active-gtk-window-in-python

Comment: how can I mark this question as unsolvable ?

Comment: @BaronLeonardo You can reply to your own question saying the feature doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This feature doesn't exist in `gdk`.